# mySQL replacing wildcard in views with specified column list

Tags: mysql, view

After creating view (simplified) as follows:

```
create view testView as
select t1.* from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
where t1.value = someValue
```

When attempting to edit it, the wildcard has been replaced with the actual column names for the table.

This is annoying for me as when new columns are added to the table, as I require to manually add them to the view, or save the create script and then re-execute it after table modifications are made.

Is there a way to retain the wildcard for editing? In MSSQL the wildcards were retained when editing a view and I could simply execute sp_refreshview [viewname] to update the view to include any new columns on the tables.

Answer (score 3):

From the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/index.html) for [`CREATE VIEW`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-view.html):

> The view definition is “frozen” at creation time, so changes to the
>   underlying tables afterward do not affect the view definition. For
>   example, if a view is defined as `SELECT *` on a table, new columns
>   added to the table later do not become part of the view.

So the short answer is no, you can't retain the wildcard.

Comment: Thanks Sean. I had read that, but was hoping there was a way around it. I'll stick to saving the create scripts.